# Trouble with old ornamental orange tree

Tags: plant-health, citrus

My 40-year-old orange tree, originally bought by my mother's friend at the local grocery store as a tiny house plant, has been looking very sad for a while.  the main problem is that the leaves are turning brown on the edges.  I've been making sure it gets enough water, but that doesn't seem to have helped.  Does anyone have any suggestions of how to remedy this?  I'm thinking of cutting it way back and hoping that might help but I'm a little scared.  thanks!

Comment: pictures of top and bottom of leaves please

Answer (score 2):

Allow the soil to dry out in between watering! The pot will feel very light versus its weight when soaked.  Get used to how this feels.  Repot it into a pot just a little bigger...2"?  Use good potting soil, no rocks in the bottom (causes perched water table), water thoroughly and allow to dry (soil will be slightly moist).  The brown tips could be from overwatering or salt accumulation in the soil. Use an extended release fertilizer according to directions. Fertilizer IS NOT PLANT FOOD.  More is not better, especially when you have a plant that is under stress.